# warning: espcomm_sync failed error: espcomm_open failed

Tags: arduino-ide, arduino-esp8266

I am a newbie on sonoff, trying to flash its firmware to sonoff tasmota.

I have tried several times to program it but i always fail. I have changes my usb to ttl device twice and still unsuccessful. Any ideas i can try?

I read in some places to ground GPIO or add a 10k resistor to GPI-0 and GPI-10, but which is GPI-0 and GPI-10 and what is the logic behind this, could someone please explain?

source of above explanations:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41355134/2174080

error log from arduino IDE

sptool v0.4.9 - (c) 2014 Ch. Klippel 
    setting board to ck
    setting baudrate from 115200 to 115200
    setting port from /dev/tty.usbserial to /dev/cu.SLAB_USBtoUART
    setting address from 0x00000000 to 0x00000000
    espcomm_upload_file
    espcomm_upload_mem
opening port /dev/cu.SLAB_USBtoUART at 115200
    tcgetattr
    tcsetattr
    serial open
opening bootloader
resetting board
trying to connect
    espcomm_send_command: sending command header
    espcomm_send_command: sending command payload
trying to connect
    espcomm_send_command: sending command header
    espcomm_send_command: sending command payload
trying to connect
    espcomm_send_command: sending command header
    espcomm_send_command: sending command payload
resetting board
trying to connect
    espcomm_send_command: sending command header
    espcomm_send_command: sending command payload
trying to connect
    espcomm_send_command: sending command header
    espcomm_send_command: sending command payload
trying to connect
    espcomm_send_command: sending command header
    espcomm_send_command: sending command payload
resetting board
trying to connect
    espcomm_send_command: sending command header
    espcomm_send_command: sending command payload
trying to connect
    espcomm_send_command: sending command header
    espcomm_send_command: sending command payload
trying to connect
    espcomm_send_command: sending command header
    espcomm_send_command: sending command payload
warning: espcomm_sync failed
error: espcomm_open failed
error: espcomm_upload_mem failed
error: espcomm_upload_mem failed

Comment: i ve done to upload sketch to esp following this guide `https://hackster.imgix.net/uploads/attachments/185205/ESP8266_starter_arduino.jpg?auto=compress%2Cformat&w=680&h=510&fit=max` Using Arduino Uno to Flash the code to ESP8266

Comment: 5v is my last trial, have done with breadboard power and uno 3.3v, but no luck, same error like you

Comment: i remeber reading somewhere about adding a 10k resistor... havent tried it and dont have a link....
will share the link if i find it

Comment: GPIO0 should be connected to ground while flashing to enable it to be flashed. if it is connected to high it will load the program in its memory and you can not upload a new code to it.

Comment: Thanks all, i found out my problem... my soldering was not done properly hence the issue... thanks guys!!!